# SSL Certificate Issue with Multiple Domains on One Apache2 Server

Tags: ssl, apache2

I have a server running a LAMP stack:

```
me@server:~$ sudo apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)

me@server:~$ cat /etc/*-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
...
```

On this server I have many two domains - one with SSL and one without SSL - and everything is currently hunky-dory.

I am trying to add SSL to the second site but requests to the second site fail with the issue:

```
[FIREFOX]
domain2.com uses an invalid security certificate. 
The certificate is only valid for the following names: domain1.com
Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN

[CHROME]
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

*Note 1: I have checked my version of Apache allows multiple SSL sites on the same server.*

This leads me to believe that the SSL files being read when `domain2.com` is called are actually the files relating to `domain1.com`.

Curiously, if I disable `domain1.com` using `sudo apache dissite domain1`, the SSL works just fine on `https://domain2.com`. This would indicate that the SSL is *installed* correctly but the sites across the server are not all *configured* correctly.

The `.conf` files are below:

```
me@server:~& cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain1
[...Port 80 config redacted...]
<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain1/server.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain1/key.txt
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain1/intermediate.crt

  ServerName domain1.com
  ServerAlias www.domain1.com

  <Directory /var/www/domain1>
    [REDACTED]
  </Directory>

  [Logging information redacted]
</VirtualHost>

    me@server:~& cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain2
[...Port 80 config redacted...]
<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain2/server.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain2/key.txt
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain2/intermediate.crt

  ServerName domain2.com
  ServerAlias www.domain2.com

  <Directory /var/www/domain2>
    [REDACTED]
  </Directory>

  [Logging information redacted]
</VirtualHost>
```

So it is clear both sites have the same configuration items applied but relative to the specific SSL files on the server for that site. Note, the SSL bundles for each site are provided from the same vendor.

Further, the certificates should be correct:

```
me@server:/etc/apache2/ssl/domain1$ openssl x509 -in server.crt -noout -subject
subject= /CN=www.domain1.com

me@server:/etc/apache2/ssl/domain2$ openssl x509 -in server.crt -noout -subject
subject= /CN=www.domain2.com
```

From all of this, please can some enlighten me as to why requests to `domain2.com` fail when `domain1.com` is enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yeah.. doing the above was all fine and should work.

If it doesn't work, be sure to check the spelling of the `ServerName` fields and to not work too late at night!